# gcc rules of global data memory layout

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, assembly, internals

I know that this is not (and has not to be) standardized, but I'd like to know if gcc has any rule or predictable pattern about placing storage for global data in program memory. That is, if I have a `foo.c` with `int a, b;` in a global scope, then a `bar.c` with `int c, d;` in a similar manner, then what assumptions can I make about the relative positions of a, b, c, d in the memory address space of my compiled program?

Comment: It's not standardized for a reason: you shouldn't ever rely on this kind of information, or make any assumptions about it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't make any. The linker can do whatever it wants in optimizing the layout.